# How can I get all the occurrences of a provided expression from a text?

Tags: java, regex

How can I get all the occurrences of a provided expression from a text?

Basically I want to fetch all the DB names from the query below that are matching the expression:

```
^.*ALTER TABLE \`(?:([a-zA-Z0-9_]+))` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY.*
```

The text that I'm trying to match is:

```
.....
ALTER TABLE \`table1\` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(`column1`,`column2`);
....
ALTER TABLE \`table2\` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(`column1`,`column2`);
...
ALTER TABLE \`table3\` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(`column1`,`column2`);
..
```

The output of the match should return: `table1, table2, table3`.

Currently the expression provided above will only return the last matching value: `table3`

Comment: what flavor of regex per/.net/python

Comment: And was also testing it on : http://regex101.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just this is enough:

```
ALTER TABLE `([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY
```

Drop all the surrounding `^.*` and `.*`, they are consuming text.

You are also having a non-capturing group, which I have removed.

Note that you must use `find()` in a while loop to get all the matches.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But what if I don't want to use the find() functionality? I basically want a regex to return that collection. Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: @gelugara: Nope. Java doesn't provide such a convenient API.